# Animation background color to overwrite from top

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to overwrite the background color from the top to bottom. More specifically, I would like it to be filled from top to bottom. Currently I have managed to produce a "faded" animation.

This is what I have now:

```
.page-dark {
  background: #003850;
  background-color: #003850;
  color: white;
  -o-animation: fadeIt 3s linear; 
  animation: fadeIt 3s linear; 
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #ff711b; }
  50%  { background-color: #ff711b; }
  100% { background-color: #003850; }
}
@keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #ff711b; }
  50%  { background-color: #ff711b; }
  100% { background-color: #003850; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a background with two colors using [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). Set the background height to `200%` using [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), and hide one of the colors using [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position). Now animate the background position to show the other color:

```css
.page-dark {
  height: 90vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003850 50%, #ff711b 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  color: white;
  animation: slideColor 3s linear forwards; 
}

@keyframes slideColor {
  to { background-position: 0 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-dark"></div>
```

Another option is to set the color you want to hide as the background, animation `background-position` to show the 2nd background (which we create using `linear-gradient()`):

```css
.page-dark {
  height: 90vh;
  background: #ff711b linear-gradient(to bottom, #003850 0, #003850 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 0;
  color: white;
  animation: slideColor 3s linear forwards; 
}

@keyframes slideColor {
  to { background-size: 100% 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-dark"></div>
```